# I have a script that takes emails from a spreadsheet and sends emails to those emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I have it set up so it only sends an email once a Google form is submitted (that Google form is linked to the spreadsheet). The issue is it sends multiple emails to the clients once the form has been submitted. I want it so once it sends the email it won't send the email to that same person the next time around only the new people. Deleting the data in the column doesn't work for me because then it gives an error because it is an invalid email. Does anyone have any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: how about adding a column that keeps track whether an email has been sent to a given email address or not?

Comment: @ochi o so I add a column to the end. Then when the emails are being sent I change the value in that column and check the value when sending an email? How would I got about that xD is there if statements in appscript?

Comment: Pretty much that would be the logic, yes. Please read our [ask] page and see how you can improve this question and you’ll get better, quicker answers :)